# Linux Forward all the syslog

Tags: linux, logging, centos, redhat, syslog

I am working on a solution that can forward all the system events via certain UDP port to a server as they happen on a Red Hat Linux box.

a) Is it possible to do this with a bash script, if so what would be the logic ?

b) What would be the best technology/app to use for this purpose ?

Thanks

Comment: What are "system events"? Do you just mean remote syslog here?

Comment: I mean equivalent of windows event logs which is combination of the logs below<br/>

/var/log/messages

/var/log/auth.log

/var/log/kern.log

/var/log/cron.log

 /var/log/maillog

 /var/log/boot.log

  /var/log/secure or /var/log/auth.log

  /var/log/utmp or /var/log/wtmp 

  /var/log/yum.log

Comment: Most of those are already being written by syslog to those files. Are you just trying to get them sent to a remote syslog server?

Answer (score 0):

*a) Is it possible to do this with a bash script, if so what would be the logic ?
b) What would be the best technology/app to use for this purpose ?*

The syslog daemon has this capability out-of-the-box; all you need do is add one line to the syslog configuration file on each machine, including the consolidation server..  In fact, merging the logs from several machines onto one was why it was written in the first place.

Comment: I managed with rsyslog. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/01/rsyslog-remote-logging/ Thank you